# Excel - Vlookup for Rows by Checking Each Column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am not sure that I am looking for a vlookup solution but I will try to present the issue.

I have some data in Sheet1 that contains ZipCode, City, County and State. It is very possible that some typos might appear and I want to check against my reference table.

The idea is to highlight each row from Sheet 1 (my data) that is not entirely present in the reference file. It does not matter where exactly it is in the reference file but they have to be an exact match for the row in Sheet 1 to be valid.

Please see below image for exemplification of correct and incorrect data:

[image]

I avoided the concatenation of the records as I want to keep the Columns separate in both files.

*the picture has the 2 sheets in the same view but in reality, there will be 2 different sheets.

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Not VLOOKUP, use COUNTIFS, something like: `COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2,...)>0` where the `...` is the other two columns.  If it is greater than 0 then it exist exactly otherwise it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Used another concatenated column to solve this as it is way easier.

Thank you for the help.